# Why am i getting undefined with this filter function?

Tags: javascript

I'm still somewhat new to programming, I've been messing with this code for an hour and still can't figure out why its responding with undefined. I've tried it two different ways.
1st method:
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

```
function oddBall(arr) {
  var oddNumbers = arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x % 2 === 1;
  });
}

console.log(oddBall(myArr));
```

2nd Method:

```
function oddBall(arr) {
 arr = arr.filter(function(x) {
  return x % 2 === 1;
 });
}

oddBall([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I know that the filter method is working, but I'm stumped as to why its returning undefined. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is missing a return statement:

```
function oddBall(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x % 2 === 1;
  });
}
```

Comment: To simplify even further it should probably be `return arr.filter ...`

Comment: Oh man, it was that simple! Thank you so much I can continue with what I was doing. You guys are a lifesaver!