# Why does "this" gets undefined inside the filters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tested `this.$store` inside the `created()` function its work fine but when I use it on one of the functions inside filters it got **undefined**. Somebody knows how to fix this?

I've been to this links below but it doesn't help my case.

[Why does `this` inside filter() gets undefined in VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714015/why-does-this-inside-filter-gets-undefined-in-vuejs)

[Why am i getting undefined with this filter function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573968/why-am-i-getting-undefined-with-this-filter-function)

---

Here is my exact code:

```
<img :src="'/user_images/default.jpg' | user_image" />

filters: {
    user_image(value) {
        return this.$store.state.storage_path + 'user_image/' + value;
    },
}
```

Below is the exact error I got:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this is undefined"

Comment: `Here is my exact code:` is that all? doesn't look enough to do anything ... what is `filters` a property of?

Comment: Filters do not have access to the Vue instance ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5998

Comment: @JaromandaX **filters** it's part of *vue.js*, intended for text-formatting. I mean just to put that to shorten the code. This link may be helpful https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html I'm sticking to the issue, I will not put the whole code.

Comment: All good, sorry I hadn't seen filters before and I've used vue for a while now! I learned something, thank you